# Is there a listed value for a soul gem?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monsters, pricing, soul

In one of the campaigns I play an evil wizard. My PC recently learnt the spell *lesser [planar binding](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/planar-binding/)*. I'm considering binding a [cacodaemon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/daemons/cacodaemon/) to my service and having it use its supernatural ability soul lock on my PC's defeated foes, capturing their souls in *soul gems*.

I'd like my PC to use these gems as currency when my PC again uses *lesser planar binding*. Do *soul gems* have a value listed anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [*Horsemen of the Apocalypse*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8odg?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Book-of-the-Damned-Volume-3-Horsemen-of-the-Apocalypse) says a soul gem can have a value of anywhere between 10 gp and 5,000 gp or more

As the description of the value of *soul gems* in [*Horsemen*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601253737) (2011) runs over 500 words starting on page 30, it's too long to reproduce here for critique or review, but, in short, the *soul gems* generated by a [cacodaemon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/daemons/daemon-cacodaemon-tohc/)'s supernatural ability soul lock have a value relative to the strength of the captured soul that's anywhere from 10 gp for souls like those of mindless oozes to 5,000 gp for souls like those of powerful dragons to *priceless* for souls epic heroes. In short, the *soul gem*'s value depends on what soul's in it.

In the [Daemon's listing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/daemons/)

- Mindless Spirits (10 gp)
- Animal Spirits (25 gp)
- Basic Soul (100 gp)
- Noteworthy Soul (500 gp)
- Grand Soul (1000–5000 gp)
- Unique Soul (priceless)